# SATA drive stopped being recognized, but still recognized with SATA-USB adapter: how to diagnose?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure

I have a SATA drive that suddenly stopped being recognized in my OS (Linux Mint 20). Prior to this it had been working fine for a year, and I haven't changed anything about the configuration of drives or connected devices in several months.

Have tried rebooting several times and the drive never comes up.
It does still show up in the BIOS, however.

I tried connecting the suspect SATA drive via USB using one of these things:
[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00MVRS38G/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00MVRS38G)
The drive gets recognized.
I checked the filesystem and everything appears to be fine.

I also tried connecting a different SATA drive into the same port.
This drive gets recognized fine.

So it's not the drive, and it's not the port!?
What else can I do to diagnose the problem?

Comment: I would get the drive manufacturer's drive test app and test with that. It should come on a bootable USB key. That will test the overall health of the drive.

Comment: What about the used power connector? Can you hear and feel if the HDD is spinning?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention: this is an SSD

Comment: Maybe some driver regression. Check `dmesg` / `journalctl -k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom Yan's comment was spot on---this seems to have been caused by a recent upgrade to `linux-firmware`. Upgrading it again solved the problem.